# Impossible to login to Kali Linux with non-root user

Tags: user-accounts, kali-linux, non-admin

I want to create a non-root user in Kali (with Xfce desktop environment) on my Raspberry Pi. I followed [these instructions](https://thehacktoday.com/how-to-create-non-root-user-in-kali-linux/). The problem is that when I tried using `adduser` and `useradd`, the account was created, but when I log out and want to connect to it, it didn't find it.

I even tried to install the gnome-system-tool to obtain the "user manager" interface, but it didn't work. The tool freezes when I try to run it.

What can I do to create a non-root account on Kali Linux?

(Edit) I've discovered that others people had the same issue :

https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-4095.html

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?37851-Unable-To-Add-quot-Non-Root-User-quot-To-Kali-Linux

Comment: Kali is not intended for use as a normal desktop Linux. Knowing what really is for, it makes no sense to create normal users.

Comment: I understand that Kali has been created for security professionnals but all the tools included doesn't always require root privilege. For security reason, it's better (in my opinion) to have a second non-root user account for these kind of tasks and it prevent, in case of bad manipulation, to damage important file.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia certain programs won't run under a root account and require a non-privileged account to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I've been able to access my non-root user account through the interface by simply defining a password with `passwd`**.

Apparently Kali doesn't allow you to create an accessible account (on the interface) without one ;)